# How to know who will take ownership?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Recipe example

```
RecipeAddViewController *addController = [[RecipeAddViewController alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"RecipeAddView" bundle:nil];
addController.delegate = self;

Recipe *newRecipe = [NSEntityDescription 
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipe" 
                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
addController.recipe = newRecipe;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                  initWithRootViewController:addController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];
[addController release];
```

1. presentModalViewController and initWithRootViewController are retaining their arguments and taking ownership. Then two objects are released, proving that someone took the ownership. So in general how do I know which message will in result take ownership, to release the corresponding objects?
2. newRecipe is not released because the life-cycle of managed object is non of my business, is this statement correct?

UPD:
sorry for #2 the answer would be that it's retained by addController then released in dealloc of addController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule, in its simplest form would be:

> If you retain it, you release it.

However, by retain I really mean "increase retain count," and therefore creating a new object (unless it's autoreleased) counts as a retain, too.

So:

1. If you called `alloc`, you release it.
2. If you called `copy`, you release it.
3. If you called `retain`, you release it.

Other than these three cases, you shouldn't worry about releasing (assuming the third-party libraries you use follow the naming conventions). However, if you *must* know what's being retained and what's not being retained, you can check the documentation for the class in question.

For your example:

1. Factory methods (like `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`) create autoreleased objects. As a rule of thumb, if it's a class method that begins with the name of the class, it returns an autoreleased object.
2. `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` returns an autoreleased object. This is in the [documentation for NSEntityDescription](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html).
3. delegates are almost never retained, in order to prevent retain cycles.
4. With the exception of delegates, you don't need to care about what goes on in a class. If you pass it a property, it's its job to retain or copy it if it needs to. All you need to care about is balancing your retains and releases.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cocoa Memory Management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) tell you all you need to know.

To answer your questions:

1. You don't care what other objects are doing in terms of release/retain.  Assume they follow the rules, and you'll be OK (or it's a bug in their code).
2. you should not release newRecipe because you didn't obtain it with new, alloc or a method containing copy.  Also you did not  retain it.

Comment: Nice reminder about `new`. Not sure if anyone uses it, though.